# How to Pandas renaming column names and prepend 0's to record?

Tags: python, pandas, insert, dataset, rename

this is just example DataFrame I made up. I have output how I would like to see. There is two thing I am trying to achieve here.

1. Replace periods `.` in the column names with `_` underscore. I can
   to this individually but I want do this in loop, like if we assume
   there is 40-50 column names.
2. check if `Car.Mile` is 5 digits on the record.  If not preprend 0’s

```
      car.Model   car.Color     car.Year   car.Mile
0       AUDI            RED        2015      14000
1       BUIC            WHITE      2015      9000
2       PORS            BLUE       2016      7000
3       HONDA           BLACK      2015      100000
```

**OUTPUT**

```
   car_Model   car_Color     car_Year   car_Mile
0       AUDI            RED        2015      014000
1       BUIC            WHITE      2015      009000
2       PORS            BLUE       2016      007000
3       HONDA           BLACK      2015      100000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) for replacing `.` Then convert column `car_Mile` to string by [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html) and last [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html) `zfill`:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('.', '_')
df['car_Mile'] = df['car_Mile'].astype(str).apply(lambda x: x.zfill(6))
print df
  car_Model car_Color  car_Year car_Mile
0      AUDI       RED      2015   014000
1      BUIC     WHITE      2015   009000
2      PORS      BLUE      2016   007000
3     HONDA     BLACK      2015   100000
```

Or:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('.', '_')
df['car_Mile'] = df['car_Mile'].astype(str).apply(lambda x: '{0:0>6}'.format(x))
print df
  car_Model car_Color  car_Year car_Mile
0      AUDI       RED      2015   014000
1      BUIC     WHITE      2015   009000
2      PORS      BLUE      2016   007000
3     HONDA     BLACK      2015   100000
```

EDIT:

Thank you [Edchum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35774073/how-to-pandas-renaming-column-names-and-prepend-0s-to-record#comment59227537_35774197) for improvement - `apply` is not necessary, better is use [`str.zfill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.zfill.html):

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('.', '_')
df['car_Mile'] = df['car_Mile'].astype(str).str.zfill(6)
print df
  car_Model car_Color  car_Year car_Mile
0      AUDI       RED      2015   014000
1      BUIC     WHITE      2015   009000
2      PORS      BLUE      2016   007000
3     HONDA     BLACK      2015   100000
```

Comment: You're Awesome!! Thank you so much. It worked like charm! I was looking for this past couple days! Thank you so so much!

Comment: I just did. one last question, if you know, if not its perfectly fine. If index 3 is missing car_Year record for honda. I want to be able raise an error and drop these entry.

Comment: Please give me a time.

Comment: If you want drop columns with `NaN`, use `df = df.dropna()` - [`dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html).

Comment: Okay I will try that. Thank you again!

Comment: The `apply` is unnecessary there is a [`str.zfill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.zfill.html) method